# mdx distinct count performance

Tags: performance, count, distinct, mdx

I got a MDX query like below which returns average distinct count for the last 30 days and it returns correct result, but performance is not good , in my fact table there will be almost 2,500,000 rows data everyday.

```
WITH Member Measures.DailyAverageUser AS
    Avg ( EXISTING{[Date].[Date].[Date].Members},
                 [Measures].[Active Tiles Employee Id Distinct Count]
                ),format_String="##.000000"
             SELECT   Measures.DailyAverageUser ON 0,
            NON EMPTY([Action Targets].[Name].Children)  ON 1
            FROM [OLAP Pre]
            WHERE (
                {[Target Types].[Name].&[tile]},{[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&      [1],[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[3],[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[4]},
            {[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[NONE],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[AMS],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[APJ],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[EMEA]},{[Employee Types].[Bits].&[1],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[5],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[9],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[25],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[13],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[29]},{[Date].[Date Key].&[20150428]:null})
```

I changed the query to this， but still same problem， Good thing is that this one will cache data between 20150409 ：null， when do query with 20150410：null， it will be fast.

```
WITH Member Measures.DailyAverageUser AS
             Avg ( {[Date].[Date Key].&[20150409]:null},
                 [Measures].[Active Tiles Employee Id Distinct Count]
                ),format_String="##.000000"
             SELECT   Measures.DailyAverageUser ON 0,
            NON EMPTY([Action Targets].[Name].Children)  ON 1
            FROM [OLAP Pre]
            WHERE (
            {[Target Types].[Name].&[tile]},{[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[1],[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[3],[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[4]},
            {[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[NONE],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[AMS],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[APJ],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[EMEA]},
            {[Employee Types].[Bits].&[1],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[5],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[9],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[25],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[13],
            [Employee Types].[Bits].&[29]})
```

Need suggestion on performance

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to keep everything in your slicer axis? If not, you can push everything into you member's definition like this -

```
WITH Member Measures.DailyAverageUser AS
             Avg (           
             NonEmpty(
                        (
                        {[Target Types].[Name].&[tile]},
                        {[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[1],
                         [Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[3],
                         [Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[4]},
                        {[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[NONE],
                        [Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[AMS],
                        [Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[APJ],
                        [Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[EMEA]},
                        {[Employee Types].[Bits].&[1],
                        [Employee Types].[Bits].&[5]
                        ,[Employee Types].[Bits].&[9]
                        ,[Employee Types].[Bits].&[25]
                        ,[Employee Types].[Bits].&[13]
                        ,[Employee Types].[Bits].&[29]},
                        {[Date].[Date Key].&[20150428]:null}
                        ), [Measures].[Active Tiles Employee Id Distinct Count]
                    )            
             ,
                 [Measures].[Active Tiles Employee Id Distinct Count]
                ),format_String="##.000000"

SELECT   Measures.DailyAverageUser ON 0,
NON EMPTY([Action Targets].[Name].Children)  ON 1
FROM [OLAP Pre]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is also slow?:

```
SELECT   
  [Measures].[Active Tiles Employee Id Distinct Count] ON 0,
  NON EMPTY
  [Action Targets].[Name].Children  ON 1
FROM [OLAP Pre];
```

`OLAP` can be slow with large distinct counts.